# How to check PDF is 3D or Normal in JAVA?

Tags: java, pdf, 3d

I just want to check that the given PDF file is 3D PDF or normal PDF file. Can some one know how can I do this in JAVA?

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Here is some example of extracting U3D object from PDF - may be it will help. http://www.jroller.com/cz/entry/extract_u3d_from_pdf

Comment: Did you get a resolution for this ??