# Detecting if a PDF file contains 3D element

Tags: pdf, 3d, 2d, u3d

Is there any way to detect if a PDF contains 3D element (Universal 3D object embedded) without reading the file contents? Can this information be obtained from metadata?

Comment: How big of a penalty would there be for reading the file?

Comment: The penalty isn't that big because you can break out of the stream once you found a U3D content in pdf (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731195/how-to-check-pdf-is-3d-or-normal-in-java) while reading. It is just that we want to avoid this scenario if possible because we have specific viewers for specific file formats.

Comment: Do you really look for PDF files *containing* a 3D element as object as in the linked answer? Or do you look for PDF files where such an element is actually *used* and *shown* on some page?

Comment: Do you want to display that U3D content if it exists in the file or you just need to perform a quick check if the file contains an U3D element?

Comment: I just need to perform a quick check because I already have a thrid party viewer that will handle the display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no *requirement* to put any info into its metadata about the fact that 3D elements may be contained in the document.

Some U3D writing software *may* put some hint about it into the ***XML*** metadata though.

### Long Answer

You'll have to parse the PDF page tree at least partially in order to find out.

Technically, 3D elements are implemented as ***annotations***. To discover any annotation, you'd have to follow this parsing path:

1. Read the trailer. It tells you the object number of the `/Root` indirect object of the document.
2. Read the cross reference table. It tells you the byte offsets for each indirect object within the document.
3. Go to the `/Root` indirect object. Read its `/Pages` key. This tells you which indirect object represents the root of the document's page tree.
4. Go to the indirect object which represents the `/Pages`.  Read its `/Kids` key. This tells you which other indirect objects represent document pages.
5. Go to each indirect object representing a document page. Look for any (optionally present) `/Annots` key. If present it will point to other indirect objects representing (possibly all sorts of) annotations.

Now you've found out if the PDF contains annotation(s) or not. If not, stop here. If yes, go on to determine the annotation type(s):

1. Go to all indirect objects found in the last step. They are of `/Type /Annot`. See if they are additionally of `/Subtype /3D`. If yes, you have found a 3D annotation. *(Attention, this may still not be a U3D one!)*
2. Within the lastly found indirect object(s) -- the one(s) with the `/Subtype /3D` key -- look for an additional key of `/3DD`. It points to this indirect object which contains the actual 3D stream.
3. Go to the indirect object containing the 3D stream. Its object dictionary should again contain a key:value pair of `/Type /3D`. Look at its `/Subtype` key. If it says `/U3D` you have found what you looked for...

### Short Answer

You may be lucky and harvest some low-hanging fruits by using good old `grep` like this:

```
$> grep -a U3D cc-7-july09.pdf

  /Subtype /U3D
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <135BB3D42FBD85F7C2E178> <056D9A891FB5FDCE8E> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <5FFAF35CE3CBD34FAE5360> <4DDFD6048FC6DA05> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <2E4E4FD7FEC771038BC5EA> <2A6579CC91BE0B> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <6F303AF9850721D5D1FC6C> <7D1B08BEAE4A5A9BEDBB> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <F270A04603F0DE08B8AA29> <EE5180016FFBD542> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <A1D5848F6841ADA9A3583C> <A3F8A5D45849D392EF> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <34B8650D178BBDFF61DC03> <2D8F4C7D3CD980F976> ]
  /MS /U3D
  /U3DPath [ <843CD0339FD1852CCA235B> <9719FB65A990897F> ]
```

However, this will not work for all 3D PDF documents, especially if the 3D elements are part of an object stream.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem as us, this is an approach we come up with using "iText" (free version is still avaiable).

The downside is that you will need to iterate every page through the file to check the content but it's still fast enough for us.

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(contents);
        int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        boolean pdf3D = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
            PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(i);
            PdfArray array = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            if (array == null) {
                continue;
            }
            for (ListIterator<PdfObject> iter = array.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                PdfDictionary annot = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.getPdfObject(iter.next());
                PdfObject pdfObject = annot.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);
                if (pdfObject != null) {
                    if (PdfName._3D.equals(pdfObject) || PdfName.GOTO3DVIEW.equals(pdfObject)) {
                        pdf3D = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pdf3D) {
                // if we already any of 3D element, we can break the loop
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases where it is sufficient to know if a PDF contains *any* 3D content (including, but not being exclusive to Universal 3D objects), you could also use the [VeraPDF](https://verapdf.org/software/) software in feature extraction mode. Follow the steps below to get a list of all Annotation types (including 3D annotations).

First edit VerapDF's "features.xml" configuration file as explained here:

https://docs.verapdf.org/cli/config/#features.xml

Make sure that `<feature>ANNOTATION</feature>` is included in the `enabledFeatures` element.

Using [this file](https://corpora.openpreservation.org/veraPDF/PREFORMA-curated/test/action_goto3dview.ar10.pdf) as an example, run:

```
verapdf --off --extract action_goto3dview.ar10.pdf > action_goto3dview.ar10.xml
```

In the output, check the "annotations" element, which lists all annotations that are present in the file, and look for annotations with subType "3D" (which indicates a 3D annotation):

```xml
<annotation id="annotIndir186">
<subType>3D</subType>
<rectangle lly="129.348" llx="163.939" urx="437.813" ury="331.861"></rectangle>
<width>273.874</width>
<height>202.513</height>
<contents>3D Model</contents>
<annotationName>3D3</annotationName>
<resources>
    <xobject id="xobjIndir187"></xobject>
</resources>
<invisible>false</invisible>
<hidden>false</hidden>
<print>true</print>
<noZoom>false</noZoom>
<noRotate>false</noRotate>
<noView>false</noView>
<readOnly>true</readOnly>
<locked>false</locked>
<toggleNoView>false</toggleNoView>
<lockedContents>false</lockedContents>
</annotation>
```

This corresponds to Step 1 in @kurt-pfeifle's answer above. As VeraPDF doesn't drill down to the level required to identify U3D streams, I'd suggest @kurt-pfeifle's answer for cases where that level of detail is needed.